# Replace .map(), .filter() to one function e.g. like .reduce()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one tricky question. I know that my function sucks and I want to now how I can improve it.
I have nested dropdown with 3 levels. I want to add placeholder if user doesn't fill all level.

So e.g. nested dropdown like chooose Epic/PBI/Task.

- If you choose Epic the object will be like this lables = {label:
  'Epic123', placeholder: ', PBI, Task'},
- If you choose PBI the object will be like this lables = {label: 'Epic123, PBI987', placeholder: ', Task'},
- If you choose Task the object will be like this lables = {label: 'Epic123, PBI987, TaskXX', placeholder: undefined},

```
  interface Labels {
    label: string | undefined;
    placeholder: string | undefined;
  }
```

I created this function:

```
  private getItemLabels(item?: any, options?: any[]): Labels | undefined {
    if (!item) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const mappedLabels = options?.map(option => {
      const value = item[option.key];
      return {
        label: value ? value.label : undefined,
        placeholder: value ? undefined : option.placeholder,
      };
    });
    
    const label = mappedLabels
          ?.map(l => l.label)
          .filter(l => l)
          .join(', ');
          
          const placeholder = mappedLabels
          ?.map(l => l.placeholder)
          .filter(l => l)
          .join(', '),

    return {
      label,
      placeholder: placeholder ? `, ${placeholder}` : undefined
    };
  }
```

Of course I try to imprve this and remove a lots of .map() and .filter().
So I create .reduce function. But I know that I can improve this better.

```
  private getItemLabels(item?: any, options?: any[]): Labels | undefined {
    if (!item) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const mappedLabels = options?.reduce<Labels>(
      (labels, currentOption) => {
        const value = item[currentOption.key];
        const _label = value ? value.label : '';
        const _placeholder = value ? '' : currentOption.placeholder;
        const join = (t1?: string, t2?: string) => (t1 ?? '') + (t1 && t2 ? ', ' : '') + (t2 ?? '');

        return {
          label: join(labels.label, _label) || undefined,
          placeholder: join(labels.placeholder, _placeholder) || undefined,
        };
      },
      {}
    );
    mappedLabels.placeholder = mappedLabels.placeholder
      ? `, ${mappedLabels.placeholder}`
      : undefined;

    return mappedLabels;
  }
```

Comment: Is this a code review question?  Those are mostly off-topic here.  *Why* do you want to replace `map`/`filter` with `reduce`?  Why are you writing the no-op `filter(l => l)` function?  You have various syntax and compiler errors in this code but you don't seem to be asking about them, so it's hard to know how to proceed.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the question to ask a clear, specific, well-defined question. Something like "how do I make this better" is too broad, and "how do I make this better by replacing `map`/`filter` with `reduce`" is probably still too broad or ill-defined (it seems like an XY problem since it's not clear what issue doing that would solve).  Anyway, good luck!